# How to stop Apple Pay from getting triggered when reading HCE

Tags: android, nfc, applepay, hce

I have an android device (call it phone#1) with an Android App that functions as a Host Card Emulator. Then, on a second phone, I have a different app. When I approach phone#2 to the first device, phone#2 reads the NDEF tag correctly and you can tap it to open the app. This seems to function pretty well on Android.

With an Iphone, however, it sometimes reads the tag, and sometimes opens Apple Pay.

I have a couple of ideas why this could be happening:

- Phone#1 is still reading while acting as HCE: maybe if reading could be disabled that would stop triggering Apple Pay?
- Apple Pay just gets triggered by any NFC Field, and so any HCE would trigger it. If so, is there any way to make the Host Card Emulator device not trigger Apple Pay?

Details: I am using the processCommandApdu with the HostApduService to make phone#1 function as HCE, and it is broadcasting an NDEF Tag to be read by phone#2 (All this is working - On IOS it works about 50% of the time when ApplePay doesnt get triggered)